# ipython3 on centOS 6.3

Tags: python-3.x, centos, ipython, centos6

Has anyone ever used ipython3 with centOS 6.3 ? 
I got ipython installed  (python2.6) but seems I am not able to use it with python3
there seems to be a bug for fedora 18
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=784947

Answer (score 1):

I did, here's how:

- install **python3** to /opt/python3/ with

  - `yum install openssl-devel bzip2-devel expat-devel gdbm-devel readline-devel sqlite-devel`
  - `wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2`
  - `bzip2 -cd Python-3.3.2.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -`
  - `cd Python-3.3.2 && ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3`
  - `make && make install`
  - `ln -s /opt/python3/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3`
  - install **distribute**
  - `wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.43.tar.gz#md5=a216a46dc9bec5835fa3c6041f1c77c2`
  - `tar xvf distribute-0.6.43.tar.gz && cd distribute-0.6.43 &&  python3 setup.py install`
  - and a little **pip** wouldn't hurt:
  - `cd /opt/pytnon3/bin && ./easy_install pip`
  - and finally, enter **ipython3**:
  - `cd ~ && wget pypi.python.org/packages/source/i/ipython/ipython-0.13.2.tar.gz#md5=ead3b7eb70c653b537fb9d96d71b8b2a`
  - `tar xvf ipython-0.13.2.tar.gz && cd ipython-0.13.2`
  - `python3 setup.py install`

As it noted everywhere on the web, `python 2` is utilised by `yum` and you don't want to ruin it, thus you put `python3` carefully aside.

```
[root@terras bin]# cat /etc/*release*
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
cpe:/o:centos:linux:6:GA

[root@terras bin]# ls -la /opt/python3/bin/ipython3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 307 May 27 03:18 /opt/python3/bin/ipython3

[root@terras bin]# ./ipython3
Python 3.3.2 (default, May 26 2013, 23:38:41)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```